# Get average value entry from Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, average

I am trying to get the average value from a Map using Java 8, but instead of getting the value itself I want to get the Map.Entry.

```
double average = totals.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .mapToDouble(i -> i.getValue())
                       .average()
                       .orElse(0); //Want to get Map.Entry instead
```

Comment: But the average can not be in any of your entry. If you have { 1 , 2, 4}, the average is 7/3, but none of your Map.Entry have this value.

Comment: @luk2302 Yeah, it's not "cannot be" but can not be". This form doesn't exist? :3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot get an entry like that, because the average does not even need to be a value in your map.

For example, in a map

```
{"A": 1, "B": 2}
```

the average would be `1.5`, which is not a value of the map. Which entry would you like to get in this case?

What you can do is find the first entry that's closest to the average, like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("A", 1);
m.put("B", 2);
m.put("C", 4);
// First, compute average
double average = m.values().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).average().orElse(0);
// Then, find entry closest to average
Map.Entry<String, Integer> e = m.entrySet().stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparing(a -> Math.abs(a.getValue() - average)))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: @AndyTurner: sure, thanks for the hint! I adapted my answer.